# Selenium Firefox webdriver via geckodriver results in error: Failed to start browser: entity not found

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver

I'm using:

- Selenium ver 3.0.1
- Firefox ver 47 64bit
- Windows 10
- geckodriver ver 11

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary=FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
wb=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
wb.get("www.python.org")
```

Error messages:

> ```
>    wb=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
>   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
>     keep_alive=True)
>   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
>     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
>   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>   File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to start browser: entity not found
> ```

Answer (score 4):

update firefox to >=48 to run selenium3

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.2/win64/en-GB/Firefox%20Setup%2049.0.2.exe

Comment: I tried this but did not help I have 49.0.2 firefox

Comment: @kumar... which selenium version you are using

Comment: i did a pip install -U selenium and it installed 3.0.1

Comment: This link did not install the latest version of firefox for me

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem might be a bug 
in the geckodriver.log I noticed something odd about the way the firefox.exe was invoked

> 1478478477543 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefoxirefox.exe

when I changed my firefox path from firefox.exe to capital F Firefox.exe. everyting worked

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
```

Comment: Because \f is a valid escape character but \F isn't. Escape your backslashes.

Comment: Totally yes @pastapockets, u should use `r"rawstring"` to add them as `\f`. The capital one `\F` will work ONLY on Windows, and doing `\\f` that is the escaped version.