# Entity not found issue with geckodriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, appveyor

I am trying to run selenium test and here is code which fails

```
public virtual void Init()
    {

        try
        {

            WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }
        catch (WebDriverException e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"1st attempt failed {e1.Message}");
            var ffPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
            if (File.Exists(ffPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = ffPath;
                    WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
                }
                catch (WebDriverException e2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"2ND attempt failed {e2.Message}");
                    try
                    {

                        WebDriver = new ChromeDriver();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"3rd attempt failed {e3.Message}");
                        Assert.Fail(e3.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Nothing working");
            }
        }

        WebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

    }
```

I get **Entity not found error**  This happens only one time when code is deployed through CI CD called appveyor. If i rerun the deployment then test runs just fine. So basically inline deployment fails.

Comment: You need to check compatibility of selenium web driver with firefox. Normally selenium web driver doesn't support the latest versions of browsers.
Also check "firefox.exe" case matches with file on disk

Comment: @FidoXLNC if there would have issue with compatibility then why test runs successfully during manual deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Seems silly but there is a solution provided in the following link.

[Selenium Firefox webdriver via geckodriver results in error: Failed to start browser: entity not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440839/selenium-firefox-webdriver-via-geckodriver-results-in-error-failed-to-start-bro)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. *In my case, it is because the app was running under user with less control.* So it's worth to check who runs the app, and try using admin or different user who has more privilege.